# When do we need to use JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder with UserDefaults

Tags: swift

To save some data to UserDefaults first we must encode it as JSON using JSONEncoder, which will send back a Data instance we can send straight to UserDefaults.Then reading saved data is a matter of converting from Data using a JSONDecoder. But sometimes we dont have to do that.

My question is will that method work anytime and when do i have to use it because i found this other solution without encode and decode:

```
   var allWords = [String]()
var usedWords = [String]()
var currentWord: String?
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let presentWord = defaults.object(forKey: "presentWord") as? String,
        let savedWords = defaults.object(forKey: "savedWords") as? [String] {
        title = presentWord
        currentWord = presentWord
        usedWords = savedWords
        print("Loaded old game!")
```

Save method:

```
    func save() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(currentWord, forKey: "presentWord")
    defaults.set(usedWords, forKey: "savedWords")
}
```

It's simple and faster way but Im not sure when i can use it with no worries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UserDefaults storage is a *property list*. NSString, NSData, NSArray, and NSDictionary are the only Cocoa classes that can be expressed directly in a property list. Moreover, an NSArray or NSDictionary can be expressed in a property list only if its elements are instances of those classes, along with NSDate and NSNumber. Those are the *property list types*.

If your Swift type bridges to a property list type, you can store it directly. So String will bridge to NSString, and an array of String will bridge to an NSArray of NSString, so you can store them directly.

But if what you've got is not a property list type, you need to transform it into a property list type before you can store it, and the usual solution is to transform it into an NSData (Swift Data). You don't have to use JSONEncoder for that but you do need to do it *somehow*.